# How to create bottom bar in flutter flutter like below image

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, bottombar

I am new in flutter but i need to create bottom bar like

Bottom Navigation Bar What i need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfgGW.jpg)

i have used multiple libraries
https://pub.dev/packages/motion_tab_bar_v2

but not found exact bar like this one

some how okay but not exact what i need